# FPDF Text file to PDF creates blank PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf

I have gone over this code so many times but I do not see why it is not working. I am not receiving any errors, which makes it difficult to move forward. If any of you can see why it is not working, then I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
    <?php
    // load fpdf library
    require_once("fpdf.php");

    // read the value of the URI variable src
    if (isset($_REQUEST['src'])) {
        $src = $_REQUEST['src'];
    }

    // echo $src; 
    $filename = basename($src, suffix);
    // retrieve just name of the file within the URI
    // echo $filename;
    // die();
    $content = file_get_contents($src);

    //Load PHP DOM
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    //load HTML in PHP DOM
    @$doc->loadHTML($content);

    //extract the text of a DIV element for PDF
    $text_for_pdf = $doc->getElementById('page_content')->nodeValue;

    //use FPDF
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

    //specify width and height of the cell Multicell(width, height, string)
    //load extracted text into FPDF
    $pdf->Multicell(190,10, $text_for_pdf);

    $pdf->Output(); //output the file

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($pdf->Output()));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="$filename"');
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');

    die($content);
```

As you can see by the code, in the URI I read the path and file name that are provided to the parameter "src"

For example:

```
http://localhost/?src=\\domain\server\test.txt
```

This example should use file_get_contents to retrieve the file and the rest is in the code to create a PDF file, but it generates a blank PDF file. I have tried the same with test.html, which is an html page, but it still generates a blank PDF file.

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`. The value you show for `src` in your example doesn't look correct and may be throwing an error when you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I will try to do use the ini_set when I get to work. As far as the src value, that is just an example, the exact string is different depending on the path to the file in the URL

Comment: The example starts with double slashes which is why I mentioned it and suggested an [edit] of your question to include an example exactly as it is received by your code.

Comment: Yes, the file is on a PC network, which starts with double slashes

Comment: Do a `var_dump($content);` after the `file_get_contents` call and verify that it contains what you think it should.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Dave, it turns out having ini_set errors on, showed me that I was using an incorrect path to the file. BTW, for anyone else trying to create a PDF file, this only works on txt and html files. I have yet to figure out how to do this for other type of files - specifically .prt files, which are Cadkey type of files for engineering purposes